# Ubuntu 20.04 not starting and showing strange message: dev/sda5

Tags: boot, 20.04

Updated to 20.04 recently and it was going well until yesterday, when this started. I have also windows on my laptop, for work reasons. And I hate it, to be honest.

the screen is all black and reads: /dev/sda5:clean, 210848/6553600 files,24928450/26214144 blocks

Now I can't use my dear ubuntu and I'm quite upset! Please help!

Comment: try to boot into the recovery mode by pressing the esc key (for Dell pc's, for others it may be some other key) when you start. If you get there, select the entry that says recovery mode. (Before you do that find out what you can on how to boot to rec mode and what you can do).
https://www.howtogeek.com/196740/how-to-fix-an-ubuntu-system-when-it-wont-boot/

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution is to restart `gdm`:

- Open a TTY with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.
- Login to a user with sudo privileges.
- use the command: `sudo systemctl restart gdm`
- Get back to your desktop with  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.